# error in POST selected option value

Tags: php, html, postgresql

i post this form into the next php page but only the by default value is posting plz help me to solve dis

```
<FORM name='myForm' method='post' id="myForm" action="so_entry2.php">
    <select name='select' class='selectpicker' id='select'>
        <option value='0'><------select------></option>

        <?php 
            $query11=pg_query($connect,"select emp_code, name from users where post='Dealing hand' ");
            while ($stmt11 = pg_fetch_assoc($query11))
            {  
                $emp_code=$stmt11["emp_code"];
                $emp_name=$stmt11["name"];

                print" <option value='$emp_code'>$emp_name [$emp_code]</option>";
            }
        ?>

        <option value='4'>DD</option>
        <option value='5'>JD</option>
        <option value='6'>Director</option>
        <option value='7'>VO</option>
        <option value='8'>CVO</option>  
    </select>
    <button name=forward>Forward</button> 
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['forward']))
    {    
       echo   $forward= $_POST['select'];
    }
?>
```

when i select any options it posts only by default value that is 0
now in the next page that is on the so_entry2.php

here after clicking the button only 0 value is posting
Thanks in advance

Comment: `<form></form>` and not as you have `<form><form>`

Comment: What's in `so_entry2.php` ?

Comment: <?php if(isset($_POST['forward']))
{    
   echo   $forward= $_POST['select'];
}?>

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way.

```
<?php 
        $query11=pg_query($connect,"select emp_code, name from users where post='Dealing hand' ");
        while ($stmt11 = pg_fetch_assoc($query11))
        {  
            $emp_code=$stmt11["emp_code"];
            $emp_name=$stmt11["name"];
?>
        <option value='<?=$emp_code?>' >  <?=$emp_name[$emp_code]?>  </option>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i m facing problem in posting the values to the nest page since i m using mutiple button i guess i have to assign unique value for each bt not able to find the code for this

Comment: are you using <input type="submit" anywhere in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

option value contain variable,so concatenation required

```
          <select name='select' class='selectpicker' id='select'>
               <option value='0'><------select------></option>

              <?php $query11=pg_query($connect,"select emp_code, name from users where post='Dealing hand' ");
              while ($stmt11 = pg_fetch_assoc($query11))
                {  $emp_code=$stmt11["emp_code"];
                    $emp_name=$stmt11["name"];

                print" <option value='".$emp_code."'>".$emp_name." </option>";
                 } ?>

          <option value='4'>DD</option>

        <option value='5'>JD</option>
         <option value='6'>Director</option>
        <option value='7'>VO</option>
        <option value='8'>CVO</option>

    </select>
        <button type="submit" name=forward>Forward</button>
```

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['forward']))
{    
   echo   $forward= $_POST['select'];
}?>
```

Comment: Is there any problem with form submission @Pam

Comment: having multiple forward options

Comment: `<select onchange="check_val(this.value)" name='select' class='selectpicker' id='select'>` `<script> function check_val(){ alert(val)}</script>` can you please tell me what value you got in alert @Pam

Comment: in the single form there is multiple forward button

suppose image if there are 3 rows den in each row there is forward button and select tag.  hope u can understand my prblm

Comment: can we use ajax submission

Comment: did you get the solution,i am just tried another answer@Pam

Comment: i set d forward option unique by forward$sno but still stuck in select tag

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this answer

```
    <select name='select' class='selectpicker' id='select'>
        <option value='0'><------select------></option>

        <?php 
            $query11=pg_query($connect,"select emp_code, name from users where post='Dealing hand' ");
              while ($stmt11 = pg_fetch_assoc($query11))
                {  $emp_code=$stmt11["emp_code"];
                    $emp_name=$stmt11["name"];
    ?>

                 <option value='<?php echo $emp_code?>'><?php echo $emp_name ?></option>
                 <?php
            }
        ?>

        <option value='4'>DD</option>
        <option value='5'>JD</option>
        <option value='6'>Director</option>
        <option value='7'>VO</option>
        <option value='8'>CVO</option> 
    </select></td><td>
    <button  class="forward"  name='forward'>Forward</button> 

    </td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.forward').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
             var $target = $( e.target );
    $target.closest("form").submit();


        })
    })
</script>
```

And sumission page code

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_POST['select']))
    {    
       echo $forward= $_POST['select'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: can u  jst tell me I am having multiple submit buttons.

and in a row i have 2 select options and a submit button.

how to generate unique rowid for each submit button want to make each submit and select options unique.
and post it to the next page please show me some code

Comment: i think that jquery will help you@Pam